# How to get the bigger profile picture of a facebook page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, url

I am getting an image from facebook by the URL: http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=d282e1e7c86c9270232f97ddc737df39&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi52.tinypic.com%2F2q0ixzl.jpg

Now, I want a bigger version, like 200 by 200. Is there a URL for that? If not, how can I convert this image to a larger size?

Comment: just by setting width and height of pic

Comment: Check my answer. I have provided the answer.

Comment: no it is not working .it is working inly for 90by90.

Comment: can you give me the url of the profile mentioned in the question?

Comment: Check my profile pic on facebook: its coming 180*180 in the large mode. http://graph.facebook.com/sujit.agarwal1989/picture?type=large

Comment: Thus its proved that if the image stored on the facebook servers is less than the 200*200 dimensions, you wont get it. Either you can resize it using the GD library.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Sun-Tzu/110264225728612

Comment: use this url: graph.facebook.com/110264225728612/picture?type=large , this is giving a picture of 200*160 dimensions

Comment: I hope you have found your answer. If yes then please dont forget to mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick mark. BTW, i am rephrasing the question to properly explain the requirements.

Comment: this is working for me , i can get the FB Profile pic according to requirement  http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=200&height=200

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Generally if you want to collect the profile pic of a user or page, the format for the icon size picture is:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[page id/profile id]/picture
```

and for the large picture:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[page id/profile id]/picture?type=large
```

**EDIT** Points to note:
If the image stored on the facebook servers is less than the 200*200 dimensions, you would get the image as the highest resolution avaiable eg: 128*160. Either you can resize it using the GD library.

**AND ONE MORE THING**

Facebook supports 200*600px as the highest resolution for the profile pic. It will resize an image to fit into these dimensions by maintaining the aspect ratio.

***UPDATE as on 19th Feb, 2017 ***

We need to use this new URL formation to get a desired profile image.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{profile_id}/picture?width={number‌​}&height={number}
```

[Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/2829128/vay]

Comment: @PJR - Could you please mark the answer as correct for making it easier for others to collect help from this question in future. Thanks.

Comment: Is there another way to get a bigger picture than 200*600?.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is very useful

I was looking this solution thanks a lot

Comment: is it possible to get big picture in multi-request with property fields? `http://graph.facebook.com/me/pages?fields=id,name,picture,description&access_token=[******]` <- something  like this

Comment: @loldop to get big picture with multiple request use: _http ://graph.facebook.com/me/pages?fields=id,name,**picture.type(large)**,description&access_to‌​ken=[******]_

Comment: It's large enough with this and should be updated in your answer: `http://graph.facebook.com/{profile_id}/picture?width={number}&height={number}`

Comment: @Vay - Thanks, added as per your suggestion

Answer (score 23):

If you want to get a larger picture you can just set the height and width you want like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[page id/profile id]/picture?width=[number]&height=[number]
```

More info and examples here: [Pictures - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

Comment: this should be the answer, imho.

Answer (score 7):

this will also work

picture.type(large)

example

```
 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture.type(large),name, email"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
             NSMutableDictionary *data=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
             data=result;


             fbId.text=[data valueForKey:@"id"];
             userName.text=[data valueForKey:@"name"];
             _emailFB.text=[data valueForKey:@"email"];



             NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

             NSDictionary *data3 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"picture"];
             NSDictionary *data2 = [data3 objectForKey:@"data"];
             NSString *photoUrl = (NSString *)[data2 objectForKey:@"url"];

             NSLog(@"Photo : %@",photoUrl);


         }
     }];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

YES, there is a way to get the original (most of time bigger) profile picture of a facebook page.

Actually the answer is already in the question. The original image url is already embedded in the save_image url. In your case it is "url=http%3A%2F%2Fi52.tinypic.com%2F2q0ixzl.jpg” which means "http://i52.tinypic.com/2q0ixzl.jpg"

In my case, the page for London is

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/London-United-Kingdom/106078429431815?fref=ts
```

I can easily get its fb object id by search keyword London.
I have tried to use width and height parameter. They work with user profile picture or user shared picture but can’t work with public pages profile picture.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/106078429431815/picture?width=300&height=300  // can’t work
```

The largest picture I can get it by following url which is only 180x77

```
https://graph.facebook.com/106078429431815/picture?type=large
```

But I can get safe_image.php url by using fb graph api, and the original image url is also inside the parameters' url section

```
"url": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCrtKykRotXBuaS&w=180&h=540&url=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2Farchive%2F2%2F21%2F20141005220235%2521City_of_London_skyline_at_dusk.jpg%2F720px-City_of_London_skyline_at_dusk.jpg&fallback=hub_city&prefix=d"
```

Here is code I used.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/picture?redirect=false&type=large",[firstCityPage objectForKey:@"id"]]
                    completionHandler:^(
                                        FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                        id result,
                                        NSError *error
                                        ) {

                        NSString *profileImgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [firstCityPage objectForKey:@"id"]];

                        if (error==nil) {
                            NSString *fbSaveImgUrl = [[(NSDictionary*)result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"];

                            NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbSaveImgUrl]
                                                                        resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];

                            for (NSURLQueryItem *queryItem in urlComponents.queryItems) {
                                if ([queryItem.name isEqualToString:@"url"]) {
                                    profileImgUrl = queryItem.value;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
                        }

                        NSLog(@"url: %@", profileImgUrl);

                        ...
                    }];
```

BUT, there are risks.

1. No guarantee the external image url will be validate.
2. Facebook may remove the explicit external url in the safe_image url or hide the safe_image url from developer in future.

Use it at your own risk.