# Facebook Image linking

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, image

Hi i want to know how can i get the link to the profile picture in facebook

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&access_token=<?php echo $params['access_token'] ?>"/>
```

is automatically converted into  a link (When i right click on the image and property the .JPG link is given (Below) )

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/573939_100000564553314_108738462_n.jpg
```

How could i get the 2nd link directly instead of  using graph.facebook.com/me/picture....  link ?

Comment: what do you mean by getting the bottom link directly on screen ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla - I want to actually save the image . So i need the converted Link ( the one that ends with .JPG) i dont want to use the https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture? link

Comment: Why can't you just save the image from the first link?

Comment: @wecsam - Because if the Access_Token expires then the linking wont work. But in the 2nd case its working

Correct me please if i am wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176775/how-to-get-the-bigger-profile-picture-of-a-facebook-page

Answer (score 2):

`/me?fields=picture&type=large` - will return the image as a text response instead of a HTTP redirect - note that the FBCDN URL could conceivably change at some point, so don't assume it's static

Answer (score 0):

With FQL:

```
SELECT pic FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

Selecting 'pic' will return the CDN URL to the medium-sized profile picture for the user being queried.

You can change 'pic' to 'pic_small', 'pic_big' or 'pic_square' depending on the size you want. Detailed descriptions of each are available on the [FB Developer pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)