# Is it possible to get the profile picture of a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an app with Facebook login. I get user profile pics the normal way:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/picture?type=large`

but one of my test users only has a facebook page, not a facebook profile. His userID shows up as normal, but I only get the silhouette image for him.

Is there a way, ideally parallel to the above method for users, to get the picture associated with a page, given the userID of the page's owner/admin?

EDIT: To clarify, I want to get the *publicly-available* picture that's in the 'profile pic' UI section for a page, but which isn't associated with any particular user. See https://www.facebook.com/cajitamusic for example.

Comment: Nope. A page could have multiple admins, and the user could admin multiple pages. Only the actual page id (or its alias) will get you the picture.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to ask for permission to access the user's pages first (which could be an extra unwanted threshold to use your app).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. You can using the same with 
    https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/picture?type=large

The problem for you seems is how to get object id of the page. You can try search API as it works for me when I try to get city profile picture.

```
    fbPageInfo = [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search?q=%@&type=page",[cityName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
              if (!error) {
                  // Sucess! Include your code to handle the results here
                  NSLog(@"result: %@", result);

                  NSArray* pages = (NSArray *)[result data];
                  if (pages.count > 0) {
                      NSDictionary *firstCityPage = [pages objectAtIndex:0];

                      for (NSDictionary *page in pages) {
                          //NSLog(@"user events: %@", page);
                          if ([[page objectForKey:@"category"] isEqualToString:@"City"]) {
                              firstCityPage = page;
                              break;
                          }
                      }

                      NSString *profileImgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [firstCityPage objectForKey:@"id"]];

                      ...
                  }
              } else {
                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                  // do nothing - user default image

                  fbPageInfo = nil;
                  NSLog(@"Can't get image for %@. Error:%@", cityName, [error description]);
              }
          }];
```

Also how to get bigger picture you can find it in this answer:

[How to get the bigger profile picture of a facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176775/how-to-get-the-bigger-profile-picture-of-a-facebook-page/30282723#30282723)